# Multiple Org Units in admin.google - but not showing up in Cloud IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam, google-workspace, organization

Google workspace (admin google) lets you create hierarchical Organizational Units. These show up correctly. And Cloud Identity is enabled on all the org units.

What else is needed for these OUs to show up in the GCP IAM Console?
In the GCP IAM (Organizations) , only the top level org shows up. What am I missing. I'd like all the OUs to show up in the GCP COnsole. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Workspace organizational units apply to Workspace users and devices.

Google Cloud organizations and folders apply to projects.

The two types of hierarchy are not related but similar.

If you want the same structure as Workspace, then you must duplicate that structure in Google Cloud manually.

[Google Workspace - How the organizational structure works](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4352075?hl=en&fl=1)

[Google Cloud Creating and managing organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization)

Comment: While I understand your response, it doesn't explain why the top level OU from google workspace DOES get carried over correctly to GCP (cloud console org unit). There is obviously a gap in the carry over implementation. Thanks

Comment: @user2736158 - That is not a valid argument. The structure of Google Cloud ORG/Folder/Project does not need to match the LDAP format of WorkSpace. Different services used for different purposes.

Comment: Taking your argument, why should the top level nodes even match, if they are indeed for different purposes. Sorry - it seems like a gap - both in the implementaiton (they could have easily provided an option to carry over the structure as is - or choose not to). As well as in your knowledge of this topic.

Comment: @user2736158 - I can explain what is supported. I cannot explain the decisions that engineers made when designing a product. No matter what you think they should have done, you must accept what is implemented or file a feature request. Your question has been answered.